# Problem when httpOnly and secure flag are setted to true on cookies using jsessionId

Tags: java, cookies, jboss, cookie-httponly

I'm using JBoss and Jersey for my java web application, and I need to set the flags httpOnly and secure to true in my cookies. To achieve this, I implemented a filter that adds the secure and httpOnly flags to all responses. However, I've encountered an issue where it seems like the cookies are being split. Specifically, for session cookies (e.g., JSESSIONID), subsequent calls are made on different JBoss sessions, resulting in an inability to find profile data because it appears as if I have different sessions for every call.

In my web.xml, I already have the following configuration:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        
        <http-only>true</http-only>
        <secure>true</secure>
    </cookie-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
  </session-config>
```

However, when I check the response in the web console, I don't see the flags set on the cookie response.

Can someone please provide guidance on how to set these flags to true, if I need to set to true only one of those and why the filter is not working as expected?